# Handling spaces in query using c#

Tags: c#, sql, textbox

When I click a button I run a query to search for a value that I typed into a textbox. For example, if I type "case" it will give me everything that is LIKE the word "case". However, if I put a space in between an item I am looking for, for example "Case Manager", then it doesn't return any results. When I run the query in sql of course it works because the item is in there. I am just not sure what I need to handle the spaces in the query. In my code, the param variable is the textbox text I am trying to find.

```
string Cmd = "";

protected void SearchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Str = itemdropdownlist.SelectedValue;
    Param = TextBox1.Text;
    switch (Str)
    {
        case "Section Item":
            Cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT SectionItemID, SectionItem FROM Core.SectionItem_Lkup WHERE SectionItem LIKE '%" + Param + "%'";
            break;
        case "SubSection":
            Cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT SubSectionID, " + Str + " FROM Core.FormSubSection_Lkup WHERE SubSection LIKE '%" + Param + "%'";
            break;
        case "FormSection":
            Cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT FormSectionID, " + Str + " FROM Core.FormSection_Lkup WHERE FormSection LIKE '%" + Param + "%'";
            break;
        case "Form Title":
            Cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT FormID, FormTitle FROM Core.Form_Lkup WHERE FormTitle LIKE '%" + Param + "%'";
            break;
        case "Cross Item":
            Cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT CrossItemID, CrossItem FROM Core.CrossItem_Lkup WHERE CrossItem LIKE '%" +
                      Param + "%'";
            break;
    }
    GetQuery(Cmd, Param); //Execute query
}
```

Comment: Run the debugger and get the value of the cmd variable.  Copy and paste it into whatever you use to query your database directly and run it.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes and everything works perfectly

Comment: What you do is a very bad and dangerous practice! You should never pass a text from a user to SQL server this way as a string.

Comment: Yup... can you say SQL-Injection!!

Comment: This will only be used by our developers at our own location

Comment: That's not a good excuse, bad habits are hard to break.  Also, what you say maybe true for now, but may not be later.   I can't tell you how many times I've written *non-production* code that makes it to *production*

Comment: Apart from what others have said about SQL-Injection (plus, parametrized queries are faster), what does `GetQuery` do? Why are you passing it `Param` if the query is completely constructed? Is it modifying the passed in query in any way? I'm sure we are not seeing the whole story here

Comment: `"Case Manager" doesn't return any results`: It depends what the table column contains. It also depends on the database type. In Oracle, for instance, string comparisons are case-sensitive.

Comment: @OlivierJacotDescombes no, they are not. It depends on the collation. If you use any of the \*-_ci collations they will be case insensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I think you are asking the wrong question.  You should never build SQL queries by concatenation of user input.  This will open you up to easy SQL injection attacks.

Use a parameterized query instead:

```
Cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT CrossItemID, CrossItem FROM Core.CrossItem_Lkup WHERE CrossItem LIKE @CrossItem";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrossItem", string.Format("%{0}%", Param));
```

More info here: 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/

Comment: Thank you! This worked I will remember this from now on

Comment: Why does this answer slove the space problem?

Answer (score 0):

param = textbox1.Text.Replace(" ", "%");

Makes "some text" "some%text"

Comment: I debugged further and I see incorrect syntax near 'varchar' but I will try with your new solution

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use `%`very carefully

```
 /* In the Following query by using `% %` you mean you are looking for exactly the same keyword*/
SELECT * From YourTable where column LIKE '%" + Param + "%'";
```

Take a look on some examples

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a City starting with the letter "s":

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE 's%';
```

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a City ending with the letter "s":

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE '%s';
```

The following SQL statement selects all customers with a Country containing the pattern "land":

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '%land%';
```

Using the NOT keyword allows you to select records that do NOT match the pattern.

The following SQL statement selects all customers with Country NOT containing the pattern "land":

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country NOT LIKE '%land%';
```

Reference : [w3School](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) , [TutorialPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-like-clause.htm)

Comment: But what if the user enters in a word in between the words they are looking for. And its neither at the beginning or at the end.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: @user3339242: if you are looking between words then you should use SQL Full Text Search 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx